# Exporting List of SAML Users in an Organization

Tags: github-api

I am an Owner in my GitHub Organization.
In the Organization's **People** tab, using the **Export** pull-down menu, I can manually download the list of the Organization's users which includes their **saml_name_id** that I am looking for.
Is there an API or any other non-manual method to obtain this list?

[image: Export snapshot]

API [Get a user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-user) provides only publicized information which is pretty useless for an Org. Owner.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an elusive GitHub API which does the job.
Until I stumble on it, here is what I found and used:
https://gist.github.com/gbaman/b3137e18c739e0cf98539bf4ec4366ad.
It uses GitHub's **GraphQL**.

Answer (score 0):

As per official [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/members) you can use `https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/members` to obtain the list of organization users. To use the API, you will need to generate a personal access token (PAT). You can do this by going to your `GitHub` settings page and clicking on the "Personal access tokens" tab.

Once you have generated your PAT, you will need to include it in the Authorization header of your request. The Authorization header should be in the following format:

```
Authorization: Bearer {your-pat}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I have done; I ran the members API to obtain the list of the Org's members and then looped through it to obtain the individual members' info using `https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/users/{username}`. This did not provide the info I was looking for.

Comment: In question you have used `/users/{username}` API at least the link you provided redirects there

Comment: @Avi does it answer your question ?